# Predict Even When Missing Values for Regression Variables in R

Tags: r, prediction, na, missing-data, predict

I have the resulting regression coefficients in R from a training data set. I now want to use those and apply them to another data set to predict values, however some of the X/independent variables have N/A or missing values which is causing the prediction value to be N/A as well. What commands can I use so that the predict() command will still predict a value for that row even if some of the dependent variable information is missing?

Comment: `predict` is generating a prediction based on the regression equation generated by your modeling function (e.g., `lm`, `glm`, etc.). That equation is something like `y = 0.1*x1 + 3.26*x2 - 0.048*x3 + ...`. If your other data set has an observation (a row) that is missing a value for, say, `x3`, then there's no way to get a prediction of `y` for that observation, because there's no value to plug in for `x3`. To get predictions you could (1) impute the missing values in the other data set, or (2) train the model only using variables that exist in the other data set.

Comment: You can use the `mice` package. This package and the function `mice()` can be used to impute missing values

Answer (score 2):

You need to treat the missing values. Depending on what kind of data you are dealing with, you may impute the missing values accordingly. E.g. - If the column has data type of int, you could try to replace them with a Mean or Median value. If you could be more specific about the data you're dealing with, it will provide more clarity.